# try and cache block in for loop skipping iteration in which it is encountering an error

Tags: python-3.x

In the following piece of code, I am trying to extract some data from the imdb site.I am iterating over the titles (tt000001,tt000002 etc.) which is stored in the csv file and putting the iterated value into the address and requesting the page.I am using proxies to avoid getting the connectionerror, so i put the code in the try and except block so that if any problem surfaces it can just change the proxy and the program can continue without getting interrupted.

```
for i in sheet2.iter_cols(min_row=2,max_row=diff+2,min_col=1,max_col=1):
    for j in i:
        try:
            print("getting address")
            req=requests.get("https://www.imdb.com/title/"+str(j.value),proxies=pro,headers=headers)
            soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(req.text,'html.parser')
            x=soup.find('div',class_="title_wrapper")
            list1.append(x.h1.getText())
            print(list1)
        except:
            print("Proxy {} not working, changing it".format(pro))
            pro=oneproxypls()

            headers={'User-Agent':ua.random} 
        else:
            print("Written in the {} successfully".format(j.value))
```

The problem with this is whenever it is encountering an error, it is changing that proxy but it skips that iteration, sometimes two or more, if the next proxy doesn't works also.So my question is, is there any way so that after changing the proxy it doesn't skip that iteration.Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

this need to work:

```
for i in sheet2.iter_cols(min_row=2,max_row=diff+2,min_col=1,max_col=1):
    for j in i:
        try:
            print("getting address")
            req=requests.get("https://www.imdb.com/title/"+str(j.value),proxies=pro,headers=headers)
            soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(req.text,'html.parser')
            x=soup.find('div',class_="title_wrapper")
            list1.append(x.h1.getText())
            print(list1)
        except:
            print("Proxy {} not working, changing it".format(pro))
            pro=oneproxypls()

            headers={'User-Agent':ua.random} 
            continue
        else:
            print("Written in the {} successfully".format(j.value))
```

and if continue not works try pass

Comment: if continue not work you need to replace it with pass